# Using SUMPRODUCT in Excel with filters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having problems using `SUMPRODUCT` along with a filter. I have the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(B3:B7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3:B7;".";"")))
```

I need to count how many "." are in the range. However when I use some filters, it always counts all the "." in that range, but I only want it to count the visible ones.

**Normal:**

[image: normal]

**After filter:**

[image: after filter]

How can I do this?

Comment: Please include a screenshot. It is confusing as to what you are trying to do. So you basically have a column with data where each cell can contain multiple periods? And you would like a total of how many periods in total? or do you have cells that just have a period and you want to count those?

Comment: sorry, already included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to your `SUMPRODUCT` formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(D3:D8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D3:D8,".","")))*SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(D$2,ROW($A$1:$A$6),0)))
```

[SUBTOTAL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) is able to ignore hidden rows. In this case, we use `103` because it returns `1` for non-blank cells which is useful. We have to modify it with the `OFFSET` function so that it returns the count as an array instead of a single value. The key point is in selecting the ranges.

`D3:D8` should be the range where you want to count the text.
`D$2` should be the cell directly above that range
`$A$1:$A$6` can be in any column but it must start in row 1 and have as many rows as the range where you're counting the text. I used `A1:A6` just out of habit and convenience. It only serves to give us an array of for numbers to feed into `OFFSET` so it can make `SUBTOTAL` play nicely with `SUMPRODUCT`.

[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately its not working for me. Its still displaying the total count, not only the visible ones.

Comment: Is your formula really for `B3:B7`? The screenshot you showed makes it look like you want the `pondeli` field which is in at least column D. I'll recreate your table to double-check. Also, our regional settings are different so be sure to change the commas to semicolons.

Comment: well its in E column and its whole formatted as a table. my language setting is czech, so I have this formula "=SOUČIN.SKALÁRNÍ(DÉLKA(E9:E14)-DÉLKA(DOSADIT(E9:E14;".";"")))*SUBTOTAL(103;POSUN(E$8;ŘÁDEK(E$8:E$14);0))"

Comment: I realized I had the offset wrong because I started off with the table header in row 1 but then moved it to row 2 trying to mirror your data better and I didn't update the formula correctly. I'll update and explain better now.

Comment: heres the actual screenshot http://i.imgur.com/uMdfRDU.png

Comment: @RomanŽydyk Your screenshot shows the error exactly where I was wrong in my original reply. The range within the `ROWS` function should start in row 1 and be as tall as your data table. I explained it better in the modified answer.

Comment: Again, thank you very much, but.. Either Im stupid or I really dont know.. I moved the table to make it as yours, also recreated it completely to make it "fresh", copied your formula with edited (translated) functions and changed commas to semicolons, but still this ... http://i.imgur.com/XoyxMZ2.png ... Im on Mac with Office 2016

Comment: @RomanŽydyk `A1:A4` has 4 rows and `D3:D8` has 6 rows. That may be part of it. Change `A1:A4` to `A1:A6`. Also, the parentheses are wrong. It looks like the `SUBTOTAL` function is *outside* the `SUMPRODUCT` function. Remove one parentheses from `))))*SUBTOTAL` and add one to the very end of the formula.

Comment: You're a genius! That ")" solved it. Thank you so much, you saved me. (I copied your formula and edited functions, but excel gave me error that I have mistake in formula so suggested me to "repair" that formula - which appears that deleted that ")"). Again thaks a lot.